# Header background isn't tall enough to wrap the entire header

Tags: bug, status-completed

I noticed that the header area could use more padding.

[image: Header]

As you can see the "ask question" link is half on the gray background and half on the white. Plus the corners of the sideways hourglass overlap the white.

You can see it even more dramatically when you are asking a question.

[image: Header when asking a question]

Comment: Yes and in the main site as well.

Comment: I've reported this previously on meta.se when it was still in beta (it rolled out to mods before everyone else).

Comment: This issue popped up again for me. These two screenshot were taken today: imgur.com/a/Gc1GX

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke - same here, I've removed the status-complete and pinged Pawel to take another look.  Thanks for reporting it

Comment: @AJHenderson it appears to be fixed now (at least for me) so you can probably put the status-complete tag back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Hey, thanks for reporting. The new topbar is slightly bigger than the old one that's why header was a bit misaligned. This is now fixed in our development environment and should be up for all of you in couple hours.

Comment: @Erik thanks for letting me know, indeed still something off on Firefox – I will take a look at this again.

Comment: There also appears to still be a couple pixels above the image of the week as well.  I'm not sure if that's fixable or not as I vaguely seem to remember it being an issue on the previous header as well.  But if it is fixable, it'd be nice.

Comment: Hey pawel, this seems to have become an issue again.

Comment: @AJHenderson thanks, will look into this again. reason is we've recently changed topbar height (again) to be in line with other topbars and well... math is hard.

Comment: @pawel lol, I know how that goes.  I'm a framework architect so I run in to messing up the edge cases all the time.  80 percent of the work for 20 percent of the situations was way conservative.